# Word counting using streams

Tags: java, java-8

I tried to count words with Streams in Java. Here's what I tried:

```
public static int countWords(String s) {
    return s.chars().reduce((x, y) -> {
        if((char)y == ' ')
            ++x;
        return x;
    }).orElse(0);
}
```

But `countWords("asd")` return 97. Why? I thought that `chars` returns `IntStream` which actually consists of `char`s. So, I just cast it to `char`. What's wrong?

Comment: @LoganKulinski What do you mean `ArrayList`? I don't use `ArrayList` :).

Comment: The int value of 'a' is 97.

Comment: @LoganKulinski Why not just `str.chars().count()`?

Comment: @Nikem: or `str.length()`?

Comment: @Holger we are in "the streams era" :). But you are right of course

Answer (score 8):

While your question refers to counting words your code seems to be designed to count spaces. If that's your intention then I would suggest:

```
input.chars().filter(Character::isSpaceChar).count();
```

That avoids many of the casting complications you have in your code and you can change it to `isWhitespace` if that makes more sense for your domain.

If, however, you wish to count words then the simplest solution is to `split` on whitespace then count non-empty words:

```
Pattern.compile("\\s+").splitAsStream(input).filter(word -> !word.isEmpty()).count();
```

Comment: Though the latter still counts subsequences of adjacent non-whitespace characters, which are not necessarily words.

Answer (score 7):

There are different overloads of the reduce operator:

- Optional reduce(BinaryOperator accumulator)
- T reduce(T identity, BinaryOperator accumulator)
- U reduce(U identity, BiFunction accumulator, BinaryOperator combiner)

If you don't specify the identity value for 'x', the reduce operator takes the first value from the stream. So 'x' ends up being the letter 'a', as an integer, which is 97. You probably want to change your code to this:

```
public static int countWords(String s) {
    return s.chars().reduce(0, (x, y) -> {
        if((char)y == ' ')
            return x + 1;
        return x;
    });
}
```

Comment: Unfirtunately, your example is not quite correct. First of all it returns 0 if there's one word. Secodenly, orElse(0) does not compile.

Comment: You're right - removed the .orElse, OP can decide how this should handle 1 word cases, as there are plenty of alternatives suggested by others as well. This answer was intended to explain _why_ the OP is getting the behaviour they described.

Comment: Besides it *is* an `int`, not an `Integer`, I didn’t notice that it is returned as well. Still, returning the value without modifying the parameter is much cleaner. Oh, and the whole thing still is an abuse of `reduce`…

Comment: Yes, as I've already commented, this answer was intended to explain _why_ the OP is getting the behaviour they described.

Comment: Maybe it helps, understanding that `CharSequence.chars()` returns an `IntStream` instead of a `Stream`. That influences the available `reduce` methods.

Comment: Oh yeah. Brain fart.

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest more functional approach:

```
public static long countWords(String s) {
    return Arrays
            .stream(s.split(" "))
            .filter(w -> !w.isEmpty())
            .count();
}
```

Comment: Much simpler: `return s.trim().split("\\w+").length;`

Comment: @Aconcagua Even the answer is verbose, it's more informative. :) I don't know which one is more appropriate when it comes to performance

Comment: @CrazyNinja If it comes to performance, then we'd probably rather stick with the `reduce` approach (just iterating, no new objects... (except for the one the lambda is mapped to)). Between our two variants? Well, if you split via "\\w+", too, you'd construct less string objects, *might* give you a little performance gain. trim() vs. stream().filter()? Would tend to say 'trim()', but don't dare to give definite answer without benchmarking...

Answer (score 2):

While using reduce, you're working with tuples : `x` being the first char or an accumulator and `y` the secone char variable.

Here, `x` always points to `a` which ASCII value is `97`

---

### `Pattern#splitAsStream(CharSequence)`

You may want to use this method in your case, it does the job just right and you write an easier to maintain code.

```
public static int countWords(String s) {
    return (int)Pattern.compile(" ")
                       .splitAsStream(s)
                       .count();
}
```

Comment: That's not entirely true - the values are passed in to the accumulator function one at a time, along with the result of accumulation. It's not a tuple of values from the stream, but a tuple of the accumulated value and the next value to be added, so 'x' could just as easily be a StringBuilder, a List, or anything else.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson Indeed, I thought of it.

Comment: @Andrew Williamson: The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#reduce-int-java.util.function.IntBinaryOperator-) clearly says that the reduction operator must be *associative*, which implies that `(a op b) op c` must have the same result as `a op (b op c)`. This is violated if `a` is a counter and `b` and `c` are characters. So even if it happens to work with the current implementation, it’s not correct. And you *will* get surprises in parallel execution.

Answer (score 1):

Counting spaces: see sprinter's response; performance: see comments to erkfel's response; correct application of reduce: see Andrew Williamson's response.

Now I combined them all to the following:

```java
public static int countWords(String s)
{
    int c = s.chars().reduce(0, (x, y) ->
        {
            if(x < 0)
            {
                if(Character.isWhitespace(y))
                {
                    x = -x;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(!Character.isWhitespace(y))
                {
                    x = -(x + 1);
                }
            }
            return x;
        });
    return c < 0 ? -c : c;
}
```

This counts real words, not the whitespace, in a very efficient way. There is a little trick hid within: I am using negative values to represent the state "within a word" and positive values to represent "within whitespace sequence". I chose this for not having to carry an additional boolean value, saving us from writing an explicit class implementing IntBinaryOperation (additionally, this keeps the lamda expression stateless, still parallelising as talked of in the [reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Reduction) article would not be possible as this operator is *not* associative...)).

*Edit:* As Holger pointed out (I think rightly), this usage is abuse of how recude actually is intended (have several alike values and reduce them to a single one still alike the original ones; example: summating or multiplying a list of numerical values, result still is numerical - or concatenating a list of strings, result still is a string).

So simply iterating over the string seems to be more appropriate:

```java
public static int countWords(String s)
{
    int count = 0;
    boolean isWord = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        if(isWord)
        {
            if(Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i)))
            {
                isWord = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(!Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i)))
            {
                ++count;
                isWord = true; 
            }
        }
    return count;
}
```

I personally like compact variants, although less understandable:

```java
public static int countWords(String s)
{
    int count = 0;
    boolean isWord = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        boolean isChange = isWord == Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i));
        isWord ^= isChange;
        count += isWord & isChange ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Don’t talk about parallelising, this abuse of `reduce` will break awfully when being used in parallel. And I’m not talking about the possibility of in-word splitting. This reduction operator is incapable of combining the results of two parallel evaluations, as it assumes that `x` and `y` have a different meaning.

Comment: @Holger You are right, real problem is lack of associativity... Improved the wording a little.

Answer (score 1):

Streams? How about:

```
int wordCount = str.trim().split("\\s+").length();
```

If you desperately must use streams (not recommended):

```
int wordCount = Arrays.stream(str.trim().split("\\s+")).count();
```